how does python functions inside 'Class Solution' get called automatically in LeetCode
in leetcode python problems, we have the following structure--
Class Solution:
   def function():
      {some code here}

i completed the function of the specific problem but i didn't call the function or get input from the user. but it seems user input and function calling are automatically handled, code is running properly, how is this happening? i'm new to leetcode, plz explain
if i tried to change the class name to something else suppose 'Solution123' it shows an error and says class name must be 'Solution', what is goin on

If the function name was part of the question statement, that means they expect you to write our code within that function and it would be called. If you do this with a different function name, it wont be called.

Apparently LeetCode imports (or exec) your text, looks for Solution class and call its function method with various inputs for tests

It simply executes Solution().function()

It's hard to answer without looking at the actual code, but imagine implementing something like leetcode yourself, what would you do?
Here's a naive approach:

Create a test harness that takes a file with a solution as parameter.
Load the provided file, instantiate the class within and run the function (both have predefined names) to test the solution.
Do this with multiple different parameters, basically those are unit tests.
Verify results and compare them with expected values.
Catch exceptions and report them as failure.

Basically, this resembles TDD (Test-Driven Development), which could be a good starting point for you. Start by implementing unit tests with Python's built in test facilities.
Anyhow, with a simple approach as above, you will open yourself up to a bunch of problems:

Code may run in an endless loop.
Code may abuse your computer to mine some cryptocurrency.
Code may abuse your computer to run attacks (DDOS) on other systems.
Code may exfiltrate data from your system or overwrite important data there.
Code may even crash your Python interpreter, giving the attacker remote execution abilities.

In summary, lots of bad things can happen, either due to faulty or malicious code. You will have to sandbox the execution more than just with try / except to run a stable operation. For example, you can run the code in a separate process with restricted access to system resources, with a watchdog that will ensure it behaves and kills it on timeout. Perhaps use some container technology like Docker, which also allows restricting network access to prevent DDOS attacks and only provides a limited amount of filesystem access on the host.
